# Error while trying to activate Process Builder flow

Tags: process-builder

I am getting the following weird screenshot when I try to activate my process builder flow.

Has anyone experienced like this ?.

I am not able to find any help online with respect to this.

[image]

Comment: Saw a similar error (don't recall the exact error id) when migrate process using Eclipse. I had old Eclipse plugin and updated plugin. Also, changed the api version in meta data before upload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is the error message shown by Salesforce when you are hitting the allowed limits of 50 rules/flows per object.

I thank Salesforce for providing such a clear message :)